# Question about product of inertia of rolling disk

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

If a uniformly distributed mass, as a perfectly symmetric circular disk, performs a rolling motion or trans-rotational motion on a stationary plane, with $\alpha$ angular acceleration about it's centre of mass. In this case the product of inertia is always zero, is it true or not?

Comment: Difficult to understand what you've written.

Comment: Product of inertia means off diagonal elements of inertia tensor

Comment: Is it rolling down an inclined plane or along a horizontal plane?

Comment: Inclined and horizontal Both